# What browsers support timezone conversion automagic?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, timezone

This example should display "Mon Dec 25 1995 07:30:00 GMT-0600 (CST)" if you're on a -6 time:

```
(new Date('Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT'))
```

or js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nFADG/

Is this sort of conversion supported in IE and older Firefoxes?

For all the crazy methods that a google search offers to convert timezones in js one might start thinking there's something wrong with this one.

Edit: removed the toLocaleString() to avoid confusion.

Edit: changed the date string to reflect the IETF standard since it actually wasn't parsing properly in FF. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 1):

I would think that all browsers in themselves support the conversion. However the underlying OS is just as important, if you are on a machine with un-updated or incomplete zoneinfo files you will have problems in certain edge cases. The browser will base its conversion on information in the OS.

When working with timezone detection I've come across several such cases, and I've not really come up with a solution. Except to hope that most of your users are not in say... Gaza, on say... Windows XP without even service pack 1.

Answer (score 0):

Supported in all browsers, except Chrome:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLocaleString.asp

Comment: Thanks! But i really don't care about the localestring function. What I need is to make sure that the time will be converted precisely. Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: Well. I guess there's only one way to find out. http://jsfiddle.net/jookyboi/9tpMn/

Give that a shot in each browser and see if the number stays the same.

Comment: Would love to but I don't have access to IE and I'd rather find the spec than install every version of firefox.